# Install packages for python interpreter of specific software

Tags: python, pip

I have a question regarding installing a python package like **pathlib2** for the python interpreter that comes with a software called Nuke for example.
In this case the python executeable is located in the following directory

```
C:\Program Files\Nuke11.1v6\python.exe
```

Because it is shipped by a piece of software, it looks a little different to your default python installation, at least for my knowledge. For example, I believe the modules are located inside `pythonextensions\site-packages` and I cannot find the typical "Scripts" folder in which pip.py should be.

The closest thing I found is `C:\Program Files\Nuke11.1v6\lib\ensurepip\_bundled` with pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl and setuptools....... but so far nothing else

What I tried: 
I cd'ed into the Nuke folder and ran `python.exe -m pip install pathlib2` which returned with the error No module named pip, as predicted. 
I am sure it is bad practice to change the python interpreter of a software but I have no other option. Therefore I would like to modify the python version as less as possible (like using the pip it comes with if possible, instead of installing a new pip).

Second question: does a pip install always install with the compiler for the current python version in mind? For example, this article explained that the module numpy uses c compiled code, which has to be compiled against the same compiler of the python installation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ensurepip`, good. First try

```
"C:\Program Files\Nuke11.1v6\python.exe" -m ensurepip
```

to install `pip`. Now do

```
"C:\Program Files\Nuke11.1v6\python.exe" -m pip install pathlib2
```

You better remove the second question and ask it in a separate topic.

Comment: What is ensurepip?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html — a standard module added in Python 3.4 to bootstrap `pip`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Nuke10.5v8>python.exe -m ensurepip results in the following: No module named ensurepip

Comment: You question mentions `Nuke11.1v6` and the comment `Nuke10.5v8`. Do you have `C:\Program Files\Nuke10.5v8\lib\ensurepip`?